# Maximum product consecutive subsequence

Tags: algorithms

I need find the maximum product of a consecutive subsequence in sequence of $n$ integers.

Example:

In: $3$, $1$, $-2$, $4$. Out: $4$.
In $2$, $5$, $-1$, $-2$, $-4$. Out: $20$. $(2*5*(-1)*(-2))$.

I've done the algorithm in $O(n^2)$, but now i want to do in $O(n)$.
I know that its possible.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you explicitly define what "product of a subsequence" means to you? I would think that it's $a_1 \times a_2 \times a_3 \times \ldots \times a_k$, which doesn't agree with either of your examples.

Comment: Ok sorry, imagine you have a sequence of integers like: 4 2 1 -3 6
subsquences are: 4 or 4 2 or 4 2 1 or 4 2 1 -3 or 4 2 1 -3 6 or 2 or 2 1.... etc 
sorry for my english

Comment: (To me,) the maximum product would thus be $4 \times 2 \times 6$, so you would have to state what you are thinking. We are not mind readers.

Comment: sorry, consecutive subsequence, got it??

Comment: no, not the sum, i wanna the hightest product of one consecutive subsequence in all of subsequences possibles

Comment: like:
a1 
a1 * a2
a1 * a2 * a3
or a2 * a3 * a4 ... understand? i wanna know the hightest possible

Comment: Ah, you want the maximum value of $\prod_{i=n}^m a_i$?

Answer (score 2):

A few observations you can use to devise the $O(n)$ algorithm (working under the assumption the elements of the sequence are integers):

- Taking a zero is a good idea only if none of the elements is positive.
- Extending the sequence by a positive element never hurts...
- ... nor does extending it by two negative ones.